Is it possible to import only selected modules from a library project into an app project?
My app consists of two Android Studio Gradle projects. One is the actual app and the other is a library project that gets imported into the app project. The library project consists of multiple modules. Is it possible to import only specific modules into the app project? How do I set up the library project so it builds multiple aars, each with different modules?
